# foreach loop does not go past start of range

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am trying to build a loop that echoes each month of the year until the current month. My `foreach` loop just stays on the start and doesn't progress through the rest of the range. Here is my code:

```
$startMonth = '01';
$endMonth = date('m');

foreach (range($startMonth, $endMonth) as $month) {
    $dataValue = date('n', $month);
    echo '<td class="month" data-value="';
    echo $dataValue;
    echo '" data-id="' . $incrementYear . '"><a href="/Archive/view/';
    echo $incrementYear;
    echo '/';
    echo date('m', $month);
    echo '">';
    echo date('F', $month);
    echo '</a></td>';
}
```

Here is the output:

```
January    January    January    January    January    January
```

Each of the months has the correct link for what January should have, but for some reason, the range never leaves "01" which is the `$startMonth` and I'm not sure why. I was thinking it had something to do with integer vs. string, but removing the `'` from `$startMonth = '01';` to make it an integer, but that didn't work either.

As far as I understand them, I am using the range correctly.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

- $dataValue can be commented out and I will still get `January` 6 times, its just the link will have a data-value different than what I want. This variable has no effect on the month itself.
- If I change the bottom line of code from `echo date('F', $month);` to `echo $month;` I get:

  ```
  1    2    3    4    5    6
  ```

Comment: date function needs a unix timestamp, you could probably utilize `mktime` providing the month number or use `DateTime` classes instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that to `date()` as timestamp you always pass `01`, `02`... and that converts to ~12 first seconds of Unix timestamp. So `1970-01-01 00:00:03` is `January`.

Change your code to use [`mktime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

```
$dataValue = date('n', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, date('Y')));
```

---

```
$startMonth = '01';
$endMonth = date('m');

foreach (range($startMonth, $endMonth) as $month) {
    $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, date('Y'));
    $date = date('n', $time);
    $month = date('m', $time);
    $monthName = date('F', $time);

    echo "<td class='month' data-value='{$date}' data-id='{$incrementYear}'><a href='/Archive/view/{$incrementYear}/{$month}'>{$monthName}</a></td>";
}
```

Comment: This is the exact output I needed. It increments the link for the correct page, increments the data-value with no leading `0` and displays the correct month string. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$startMonth = '01';
$endMonth = date('m');

foreach (range($startMonth, $endMonth) as $month) { 
 $dataValue = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, date('Y')));
 $month = sprintf('%02d', $month);
 echo '<td class="month" data-value="' . $dataValue . '" data-id="' . $month . '"><a href="/Archive/view/' . $month . '">' . $dataValue . '</a></td>';
}
```

**Output:**

```
JanuaryFebruaryMarchAprilMayJune
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but if I comment out the $dataValue lines and replace the variable with a `1`, the `January` months still show up, the link just has a data-value of `1`. I thought $dataValue was causing this as well, but it has nothing to do with it.

Something is getting stuck at the `echo date('F', $month);` line. If I change that to `echo $month;` I get:


`1    2    3    4    5    6`

Comment: Updated, please check

Comment: Well, I spoke too soon. The output looks right, but the data-value in the link is incorrect. Instead of the data-value being `1, 2, 3...11, 12` its the month: `January, Febuary, March` Also the link goes to a single digit instead of the double digit I need it to go to. So the link should be something like `/view/2018/01`, `/view/2018/view/02` etc.

Comment: If you want dataValue 1,2,3 use `$month` variable and double digit updated

Answer (score 0):

Change the $dataValue from

```
$dataValue = date('n', $month);
```

to

```
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $month);
echo $dateObj->format('F');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the $dataValue doesn't have anything to do with this issue. If I comment out those 2 lines of code, I still get the `January` links 6 times.

However, if I change the line of code at the bottom from `echo date('F', $month);` to `echo $month;` I get:

`1  2  3  4  5  6`

Comment: Then try using this - `date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10));`

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
$start_date = date('Y-01-01');
$end_date = date('Y-m-01');

$loop_date = $start_date;

//loop through months
while(strtotime($loop_date)<=strtotime($end_date)){

echo date('F',strtotime($loop_date));

$loop_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime($loop_date)));

}
```